# Set up Acumatica Connector

Tags: acumatica, external, connector

Currently trying to follow the [Acumatica Connector to External System Tutorial](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=87fda905-6a19-4f51-b16c-142ad8ce6948) and running into issues with deprecated libraries and errors with naming conventions. Does anyone know where I can find an up to date tutorial?

Tried following along tutorial and keep getting errors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe they have been changing the signatures lately. Can you look for similar names or calls in the Acumatica source to compare to between what is in the help wiki and what is in the version you are implementing?